# Как правильно импортировать персонажа, чтобы можно было его анимировать?

Tags: unity3d, анимация, моделирование

Интересует такой вопрос. Я импортировал персонажа извне и вручную, прямо в юнити делал к нему анимации. Но когда я захотел импортировать анимации с других внешних моделей, оказалось что моя модель как бы "битая" и ни одну "чужую" анимацию я повесить не могу. При воспроизведении ничего не происходит. Что я только не делал.

Вопрос собственно вот в чём. Сейчас я хочу импортировать нового персонажа вместо старого и не хочу снова на что - нибудь подобное напороться, поэтому скажите, что нужно учитывать и проверить, чтобы импортированный персонаж мог спокойно и без проблем воспроизводить чужие анимации?

Формат анимаций и модели - fbx;

Первую модель импортировал из iClone.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что ваш персонаж - гуманойд, например, человек или гном.
В таком случае действуйте по вот [этой](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html) инструкции из документации unity.
Одно из важных действий, для совместимости с чужими анимациями - указать скелет (rig) персонажа как Humanoid.